# Kotlin Volley - App crashes with error while accessing volley from another class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I have only two files in project `LoginActivity.kt` & `ApiActivity.kt`. The Loin Activity will call the function called as `get()` which is inside the ApiActivity, the `get()` function will just do a simple GET call and returns the value.

This is what i have in **LoginActivity.kt**

```
val api = com.sa.sa.ApiActivity();
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        this.getToken();
    }
private fun getToken() {
var response = this.api.get ();
        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity,  response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And this is what i have in **ApiActivity.kt**

```
fun get () : String {
        var result : String = "Test";
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        var url = getString(R.string.api_url)+getString(R.string.api_getToken);
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                result = response;
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                result = "Error";
            })
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        return result;
    }
```

The IDE doesn't show any error, but when i try to run the application it shows the following error and crashes the App

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference
```

**Note :** I don't have any layout for `ApiActivity.kt` and i don't have `onCreate` too. I have posted all the codes that i have.

What is the reason for App Crash or What i am doing wrong.

Comment: Is ApiActivity a subclass of Activity or AppCompatActivity ? If not what is it a subclass of ?

Comment: Both LoginActivity & ApiActivity i have used `class ApiActivity : AppCompatActivity() {` and `class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {` Is that wrong ?

Comment: Can you try to pass ApplicationContext in Volley instance creation.

Comment: @VigneshK Thank you .. While i pass the Context to child class it works good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't make `ApiActivity` an activity at all.

```
class LoginActivity {
   fun getData(context : Context) : String {
    var result : String = "Test";
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    var url = context.getString(R.string.api_url) + context.getString(R.string.api_getToken);
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            result = response;
        },
        Response.ErrorListener {
            result = "Error";
        })
    queue.add(stringRequest);
    return result;
   } 
}
```

In `LoginActivity` call it as

```
var response = this.api.getData(this);
Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity,  response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Also isn't `StringRequest` method asynchronous ? In that case you'll always get `"Test"` back.